# .htaccess redirect 404 but remember the mistake as an url variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

My .htaccess file is one line

`ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/folder/404.php?url=%{HTTP_REFERER}`

if I go to https://example.com/folder/derp.php **(a non-existent page)**

It literally takes me to:

https://example.com/folder/404.php?url=%{HTTP_REFERER}

whereas it should take me to:

https://example.com/folder/404.php?url=https://example.com/folder/derp.php

why is `%{HTTP_REFERER}` being treated as a string?

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.com/folder/page.php.*
RewriteRule .* https://example.com/folder/404.php?url=%{HTTP_REFERER}
```

tried that the HTTP_REFERER is blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%{HTTP_REFERER}` is `mod_rewrite` variable that cannot be used in `ErrorDocument`.

You will have to use a mod_rewrite rule instead of `ErrorDocument` if you want to pass `%{HTTP_REFERER}`.

Another alternative is to not use `%{HTTP_REFERER}` at all and use slightly different `ErrorDocument` directive as this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /folder/404.php
```

and get the original 404 causing URI using:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

Comment: Tried the alternative earlier `echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` is blank! :/

Comment: That will work work `ErrorDocument 404 /folder/404.php` as I suggested. `404` handler in your question won't work as that will do full redirect.